# Number picker increase number from opposite direction

Tags: java, android, xamarin

Till now my number picker it starts to increse my number from top to bottom. Can i change that to opposite direction?

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<NumberPicker
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:id="@+id/numberPicker1" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity

```
val numberPicker = (NumberPicker)FindViewById(Resource.Id.numberPicker1);
numberPicker.MaxValue = 100;
numberPicker.WrapSelectorWheel = false;
```

Please see image below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

You can define the order by yourself. To use `SetDisplayedValues` to set an array with string values to the `numberPicker`. And then the display value of `numberPicker` will have the same order with the order of value in the array.

For example:

If you define the array 
`String[] numbers = new string[] { "10", "9", "8", "7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2","1" };`, 
then set `numberPicker.SetDisplayedValues(numbers);` and `numberPicker.Value=1;`, the display value will be from 10 to 1.

Here is the solution in your case:

```
NumberPicker numberPicker = (NumberPicker)FindViewById(Resource.Id.numberPicker1);

//define your own array here
//String[] numbers = new string[] { "10", "9", "8", "7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2", "1", "0-" };

ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

for (int i = 100; i > 0; i--)
{
      list.Add (Convert.ToString(i));
}

string[] numbers = (string[])list.ToArray(typeof(string));

numberPicker.SetDisplayedValues(numbers);
//set the min value
numberPicker.MinValue=1;
numberPicker.MaxValue=numbers.Length;
//set the default value
numberPicker.Value=1;    
numberPicker.WrapSelectorWheel = false;
```